# How to solve XML conversion Issue?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, xml-parsing, dom4j

Hi all I am using Ajax in my project for loading product name in one select box with onselect event of storename in select box onchange event. Here i used Ajax for getting listing from java action class to jsp. my code in Jsp and Action class as follows.

```
 <s:label value="Store Name : *" />                                                                        
 <s:select name="storeName" list="storeList" onchange="loadProduct(this.value)"  listKey="storeId" listValue="storeName" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select the Store"  /> 

 <s:label value="Product Name : *" /> 
 <s:select name="productName" list="productList" listKey="productId" listValue="productName"  />  


 function loadProduct(id){
var URL = "AjaxPopMyCycle.action?storeName="+id;
ajaxEditFunctionCall(URL); 

                                }

        function ajaxEditFunctionCall(URL){   
                 try{
                    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }catch (e){
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }catch (e){
                    try{
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }catch (e){
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                        return false;
                    }
                } 
            } 
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
              if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
                    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) { 
                        if(xmlHttp.responseXML != null ){                      
                                showMessage(xmlHttp.responseXML); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true); 
            xmlHttp.send(URL);
        }
        function showMessage(errorDisplayXML){   
        var checklist=document.Add.productName;
            checklist.options.length=0;  
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){

            if(errorDisplayXML.getElementsByTagName("rootElement")[0]!=null){  
                var rootElement  = errorDisplayXML.getElementsByTagName("rootElement")[0];
                var location = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("Message"); 
                var locArr = location[0]; 
                    var locArr = " ";
                    var tempArr;
                    var tempArr1; 
                    for(var i=0; i<location.length; i++){ 
                        tempArr = "";
                        tempArr1 = "";
                        locArr = location[i];   
                        tempArr = locArr.getElementsByTagName("productId")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;   
                        tempArr1 = locArr.getElementsByTagName("productnName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;  
                        checklist.options[i]= new Option(tempArr1,tempArr);                         
                    }       
                }else{
                    alert("errorDisplayXML Contains NULL");
                }
            }
            }
```

Following code in Action class for Getting result and load into XML as Follows.

detailedList contains the list of product related with store from database.

```
public String getDetails(List detailedList)throws Exception{

    Element tempElem = null,
    rootElem = null;
    Text textElem = null;
    document=new org.dom4j.dom.DOMDocument();
    rootElem = document.createElement("rootElement");
    Element errorElement = null;
    List saveList = new ArrayList();
    saveList = detailedList;
    System.out.println("DetailedList:"+saveList.size());
    if(saveList.size()>0){
        try {               
            for(int i=0;i<saveList.size();i++){

                Product aproduct = (Product )saveList.get(i);  
                errorElement = document.createElement("Message");

                tempElem = document.createElement("productId");
                textElem = document.createTextNode(aproduct .getProductId());                   
                tempElem.appendChild(textElem);
                errorElement.appendChild(tempElem);

                tempElem = document.createElement("productName");
                textElem = document.createTextNode(aproduct.getProductName());
                tempElem.appendChild(textElem);
                errorElement.appendChild(tempElem); 

                rootElem.appendChild(errorElement);                 
            }              
        }catch (Exception e) {
            tempElem = document.createElement("Message");
            return parseToString(tempElem);
        }


    return parseToString(rootElem);
}

public String parseToString(Element node) throws Exception {

    OutputFormat format  = new OutputFormat();  
    StringWriter  stringOut = new StringWriter();       
    XMLSerializer serial = new XMLSerializer(stringOut,format);

    serial.asDOMSerializer();                           
    serial.serialize(node);
    return stringOut.toString();

}
```

I have imported following packages in my action class.

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer;

It works fine with correct functionality for last 3 weeks.

But it is not getting compiling and showing following error message in my server.

C:\Users\Desktop\Updated\Project\src\main\java\com\action
\AjaxAction.java:[199,5] com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer
 is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

C:\Users\Desktop\Updated\Project\src\main\java\com\action
\AjaxAction.java:[199,32] com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerialize
r is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

My project uses Struts2, Jsp, Hibernate3 as Front end and Mysql server as Back end. I have no idea to fix this issue.

Anyone please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance!!!.

Comment: just a side not why you are not suing JSON format which is more lightweight and more flexible.S2 has build din support for JSON and its easy to use.Alternatively use XStream flexible and easy to use

Comment: thanks UmeshAwasthi. Can u send any URL to use JSON format. I have no idea about this technology.

Comment: here is the link for you, all you need to have the plugin in your classpath and you are ready to go. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer` also you can avoid the error. import this class from **[xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/xerces/jars/xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar)** and use in `parseToString()` like this :

```
import org.apache.xml.serialize.OutputFormat;
import org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer;

public String parseToString(Element node) throws Exception {
    OutputFormat format  = new OutputFormat();  
    java.io.Writer  stringOut = new StringWriter();       
    XMLSerializer serial = new XMLSerializer(stringOut,format);                      
    serial.serialize(node);
    return stringOut.toString();
}
```